# Using chrono of C++11 with _USE_32BIT_TIME_T on

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, wait, c++-chrono

The project I'm working on requires me to use `_USE_32BIT_TIME_T` preprocessor definition. So I cannot get rid of it. I also want to use `chrono` library of C++11 for a timed wait. However I cannot get it to working. Here is the code I'm working on.

```
    std::mutex *lock = new std::mutex;
    std::condition_variable *cv = new std::condition_variable;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ulock(*lock);

    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    cv->wait_for(ulock, std::chrono::milliseconds(40));
    auto finish = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(finish - start).count() << "ns\n";
```

I get the following warning. It compiles but does not work as expected. It usually does not return from wait_for, or if it does it waits for arbitrary times.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\chrono(749): warning C4244: '=' : conversion from '__int64' to 'time_t', possible loss of data
          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\condition_variable(73) : see reference to function template instantiation 'xtime std::_To_xtime<__int64,std::milli>(const std::chrono::duration<__int64,std::milli> &)' being compiled
          Main.cpp(24) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_Cv_status std::condition_variable::wait_for<__int64,std::milli>(std::unique_lock<std::mutex> &,const std::chrono::duration<__int64,std::milli> &)' being compiled
```

Is there a way to use `chrono` with `_USE_32BIT_TIME_T` on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently there is a bug with Visual Studio: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/972033/std-chrono-and-use-32bit-time-t-dont-work-togther

I ended up using `boost` instead of standard C++11 libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem.  I worked around this by changing wait_for to wait_until, passing current time + whatever delay you want

```
xtime xt;
xtime_get(&xt, TIME_UTC);
xt.sec += 10;
cvTimeout.wait_until(lkTimeout, &xt);
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_until